# Looking for examples of large hyperbolic two-generator knots or 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds

We say a knot $K$ in $S^3$ is small if its exterior contains no closed properly embedded incompressible surfaces and we say $K$ is large otherwise.

Does anyone know of an example of a large hyperbolic knot $K$ such that $\pi_1( S^3 - K)$ has rank 2?  All of the examples of large knots I can think of (4-strand pretzel knots and some knots whose complements contain embedded quasi-Fuchsian surfaces for instance) seem to have fundamental groups with rank 3 or larger.

How about, more generally, examples of large hyperbolic 3-manifolds with rank two fundamental group?

Comment: For the answer to your second question, one may find hyperbolic 3-manifolds with Heegaard genus 2 and $b_1 >0$, which are thus large with rank 2 fundamental group. I suspect knot examples exist, but I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mario Eudave-Muñoz constructed examples of tunnel number one hyperbolic knots containing closed incompressible surfaces. See Theorem 8.1:

*Mario Eudave-Muñoz*, MR 1719999 [**Incompressible surfaces in tunnel number one knot complements**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(99)00040-1), *Topology Appl.* **98** (1999), no. 1-3, 167--189.

Comment: Fantastic, Ian. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome @Charlie (Frohman? Livingston? Trotter?).

Comment: None of the above.  My last name is Katerba - I'm a grad student at the University of Montana studying under Eric Chesebro.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another set of (possibly overlapping) examples which also might be interesting. In unpublished work, Ken Baker showed that certain Berge knot complements could be large:

*Kenneth L. Baker*, [Closed essential surfaces in the complements of large volume Berge knots](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509082). arXiv preprint math/0509082 (2005).

Berge knot complements necessary have two generator fundamental group, because they are tunnel number one as well.